# Docker Mac, why can't I reach my containers by domain?

Tags: docker

I want to be able to access my development containers by using a domain name like: https://site1.dev

This is what I've done:

> - I made docker's internal IP's accessible from the host machine using https://github.com/wojas/docker-mac-network
> - This works, I can open https://172.19.0.24 in the browser
> - Now I started a DNS container: docker run -d --name dns -p 53:53 -p 53:53/udp --network  andyshinn/dnsmasq:2.76 -k -d
> - I added 127.0.0.1 to DNS servers
> - Pinging from inside the DNS container to site1.dev works

But pinging from outside the container to `site1.dev` does not work.

> ping: cannot resolve site1.dev: Unknown host

What am I missing?

Comment: edit your `\etc\hosts` file to point the `site.dev` to that IP.

Comment: Are you trying to access your containers by name from the host, or from off-host?

Comment: @DavidMaze from the host.

Comment: @TZHX yes that's possible, but the container IP's are dynamic, so I would need to need to change the hosts file on every reboot